# Require base nodejs modules in react-native project

Tags: react-native

I'm fairly new to node and extremely new to react-native. I'm trying to use some base nodejs modules in my react-native project and I keep getting a `unable to resolve module` error.

For instance, I am trying doing:

```
var buffer = require('buffer');
```

Referring, of course to https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

What piece am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

react-native is not compatible with all node modules.  It doesn't run on node runtime.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html